# Determine file-/content-/mime-type from file-like?

Tags: python, mime-types, content-type

Is it possible to determine the type of a file-like object in Python?

For instance, if I were to read the contents of a file into a `StringIO` container and store it in a database, could I later work-out the original file-/content-/mime-type from the data? Eg. are there any common headers I could search for?

If not, are there any ways to determine "common" files (images, office docs, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [filemagic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/filemagic) module:

```
with magic.Magic as m:
    m.id_filename('setup.py')
    # => 'Python script, ASCII text executable'

    b = open("image.jpg", "rb").read()
    m.id_buffer(b)
    # => 'JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should evaluate the hex signature.